# CSS3 Flexible Box Model and Fixed Aspect Ratio

Tags: css

All the examples I could find of flexible box model show stuff expanding either in the horizontal direction or the vertical direction. I could not find out how to let things flexibly expand while maintaining a fixed aspect ratio.

Comment: This might help you about other properties of the css3 box-model: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question recently in a W3C course forum, and got an in-depth reply from one of the instructors, Phil Archer. He suggests using SVG to maintain aspect ratio while scaling, and also shows by example that it works well in web browsers, but not so well on mobiles. See http://philarcher.org/diary/2012/scalablesquares for more info.