# Make divs flex but save proportions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
.alldivs {

    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;

    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizotal;
}


.div1 {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:white;
    margin:2px;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}



.div2 {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:white;
    margin:2px;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}

.div3 {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:white;
    margin:2px;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
```

How to make these 3 divs flex but save proportions? (I want them to be square or 2/3). And how to make images that I'm gonna place in these divs flex with them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Flexible Box Model and Fixed Aspect Ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757775/css3-flexible-box-model-and-fixed-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @Mathias I think the reply to that question may be outdated/a better solution can be found. Not sure though